# Why I can't format my JSON object?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to construct a json object containing inner objects.

I'm trying the following code - where `$ids` is an array containing some IDs:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($ids as $value) {
    $tempArray = getCustomOptions($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName, $_SESSION['companyId'], $value);
    array_push($result, $tempArray);
}
    print_r(json_encode($result));
```

The `getCustomOptions()` also returns an array using the following script:

```
$dataArray = [];
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
      $dataArray[] = array(
           'id' => $id,
           'description' => $description
      );
}
```

The problem is that when I `print_r(json_encode($result));` I'm getting the following result:

```
[
    [
        {
            "id":21,
            "description":"Bshd"
        },
        {
            "id":22,
            "description":"Gandhi "
        },
        {
            "id":23,
            "description":"aaaa"
        },
        {
            "id":24,
            "description":"bbbbb"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id":12,
            "description":"121"
        },
        {
            "id":13,
            "description":"qwe"
        },
        {
            "id":16,
            "description":"wD2"
        },
        {
            "id":17,
            "description":"we"
        }
    ],
    [
    ]
]
```

As you can see it returns some arrays inside of an array, but what I really need is the following structure:

```
{

    "data1":[
        {
            "id":21,
            "description":"Bshd"
        },
        {
            "id":22,
            "description":"Gandhi "
        },
        {
            "id":23,
            "description":"aaaa"
        },
        {
            "id":24,
            "description":"bbbbb"
        }
    ],
    "data2":[
        {
            "id":12,
            "description":"121"
        },
        {
            "id":13,
            "description":"qwe"
        },
        {
            "id":16,
            "description":"wD2"
        },
        {
            "id":17,
            "description":"we"
        }
    ]

}
```

I know that I'm missing something really small and basic here, but for me the JSON manipulation in php is still hard.

Can somebody give me a clue or a push?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try following code to generate your array in a proper format.

```
$result = array();
$i=1;
foreach ($ids as $value) {  
    $tempArray = getCustomOptions($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName, $_SESSION['companyId'], $value);
    $result['data'.$i] = $tempArray;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use array_push() that just creates a normal array element.  Use `$array_variable[$key] = ...` to assign values to a specific associative array key.